# I am having trouble running my program that creates html templates each time it is ran

Tags: java, html, web

I am writing a program in java that creates an HTML template each time it is ran. It reads the input bio txt file that is made up of four headings and paragraphs one line each. It takes the txt and stores the headings and paragraphs into a parallel array. I then have the array written into an HTML file. The problem is that when I run it there is no input onto the file and it also says that the reader is never closed. Here's my program and output. Thank you for any suggestions.

```
package edu.txstate.cs3320.qwt1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;


public class bio2 {

    private static final String OUTPUT_FILE = "./iofiles/bio.html";
    private static final String INPUT_FILE = "./iofiles/bio.txt";
    private static final String TITLE = "My LIfe";

    private static BufferedWriter writer = null;

    private static ArrayList <String> headings = new ArrayList <> ();
    private static ArrayList <String> paragraphs = new ArrayList <> ();

    //methods before main

    private static void initialize (String fileName) {
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void readParagraphs(String inputFileName) {
        final int numberOfParagraphs = 4;

        try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFileName));

        for(int i = 0; i<numberOfParagraphs;i++) {
            String headerLine = reader.readLine();
            if(headerLine != null) headings.add(headerLine);
            String paragraphLine = reader.readLine();
            if(paragraphLine != null) paragraphs.add(paragraphLine);

        }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    private static void writeHTML(String anHTMLString) {

        try {
            writer.write(anHTMLString);
            writer.flush();
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void writeParagraphs() {
        for(int i=0; i<headings.size();i++) {
            writeHTML(HTMLTags.H1_START + headings.get(i)+HTMLTags.H1_END);
            writeHTML(HTMLTags.PARAGRAPH_START);
            writeHTML(paragraphs.get(i));
            writeHTML(HTMLTags.PARAGRAPH_END);
        }
    }

    private static void writeBio(String title) {
        writeHTMLOpening(title);
        writeParagraphs();
        writeHTMLClosing();
    }


    private static void writeHTMLOpening(String title) {
        writeHTML(HTMLTags.HTML_HEADER_START);
        writeHTML(HTMLTags.TITLE_START + title + HTMLTags.TITLE_END);
        writeHTML(HTMLTags.HTML_HEADER_END);
        writeHTML(HTMLTags.BODY_START);
    } 

    private static void writeHTMLClosing() {
        writeHTML(HTMLTags.BODY_END);
        writeHTML(HTMLTags.HTML_END);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initialize(OUTPUT_FILE);
        writeBio(TITLE);
        readParagraphs(INPUT_FILE);
        System.out.println("completed");

    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>My LIfe</title><style> 
h1 {text-align:center;} 
</style> 
</head>  
<body></body></html>
```

Here is my bio.txt input file

```
[h1] Who Am I?
My name is Billy. I am a senior CS major.
[h1] What are my interests?
I would like to develop my skillset in software and web development and possibly start a career in it.
[h1] Why am I taking this class?
I am taking this class because I'd like to enhance my web development skills.
[h1] What is my five year plan?
My five year plan is to graduate with my CS major and earn a great job that I enjoy.
```

Comment: What do you mean by `The problem is that when I run it there is no input onto the file`? Do you mean to save(write) the array to an html file, because input in java means to read from a file and output means to write from a file

Comment: I would suggest just use the new nonblocking I/O Files, Path, and OutputStream,InputStream

Comment: What about using http://freemarker.org/  kind of template engine rather than manually creating HTML. Question not give a clear understanding about your usage although.

Comment: I meant that the program doesn't take this input txt file and save to the array and then take the array and save that information on to the html file. @abcOfJavaAndCPP

Comment: The reason I am doing this is for a class project @dwij

Comment: @QuintonThompson, No I need to know whether you want to put your questions and answers into HTML template via java code or something else? If yes rather than creating HTML template by java code you can have HTML template with placeholders and dynamically fill those place holders with real values.
Just go through http://freemarker.org/ . You will get the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small correction in the order of method execution. You need to read and initialize your heading and paragraphs first, followed by writing it in html file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    initialize(OUTPUT_FILE);
    readParagraphs(INPUT_FILE);
    writeBio(TITLE);
    System.out.println("completed");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This small correction is it exactly what I needed!

Comment: It's good practise to close both your `reader` and `writer` as well. Like this `try { ... } catch(IOException ex) { ... } finally { reader.close }`.